# A Python discord bot not responding to a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried making a discord bot and stumbled across an issue, the bot does not respond to commands and I have no clue what's wrong.
Here's my code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Python"))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
        await bot.process_commands(message)


client = MyClient()
client.run("Token Here")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Sup")
```

Comment: isn't `client.run("Token Here")` a blocking call?

Comment: yeah it probably is a blocking call, just noticed it

Comment: thats your answer then, your bot never actually runs. I'm not sure how to run both at the same time, you can maybe try threads or read more documentation

Comment: I tried putting it at the end of the code and it still doesn't respond to commands, I'll try to read more documentation, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently mixing a `discord.Client` with a `commands.bot`.
Discord.py provides multiples ways to creates bots that are not compatibles each other.

Moreover, `client.run` is blocking, and should be at the end of your script.!

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class MyClient(commands.Bot):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Python"))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
        await self.process_commands(message)


client = MyClient(command_prefix='!')


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Sup")


client.run("...")
```

[image]

---

Note that you are not obligated to subclass the `commands.Bot` class given by the library.

Here is an other exemple that don't use subclassing:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(client.user))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Python"))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
    await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Sup")


client.run("...")
```

Using the second approach might be beneficial if you just started to learn dpy, and can work when you dont have a lot of commands.
However, for bigger projects, the first approach will help to organise your bot by using cogs for commands and events.